# How to build a Redux selector for a collection that contains global and local derived data?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-form, reselect

## How to build a Redux selector for collection with global and local derived data?

I have some data that looks like:

```
{
  palette: [1,0,1,1],
  children: [
    {
      RootData: [...],
     },
     //more children...
  ]
}
```

There are some computed derived properties I need to add. `DerivedRoot` and `ComputedFromPaletteAndDerivedRoot`

```
{
  palette: [1,0,1,1],
  children: [
    {
      RootData: [...],
      // Local data for this child derived from the RootData
      DerivedRoot: [], 

      // Additional data derived from global `palette` and local `RootData`
      ComputedFromPaletteAndDerivedRoot: []
    },
    //more children...
  ]
}
```

I've looked at [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) and I'm not sure if it's the right tool to utilize in this scenario.

Individual children's `RootData` values can change and I don't want the selector applied to the full children collection as that would re-memoize all the children anytime an individual child changes. Additionally any time `palette` changes the child selectors could recompute a new value for `ComputedFromPaletteAndDerivedRoot`

Comment: I've run into a similar problem in the past. I think that reselect is the right tool, you probably want to use the [`createSelectorCreator`](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect#createselectorcreatormemoize-memoizeoptions) for this.

Comment: thanks, @Josep I was recommended that elsewhere will look into it